# How to make text appear and disappear using GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

Beginner here.
I was trying to make a simple GUI program in which when I click a button, something will appear and if I click again, it will disapper.
I'm having trouble here since Eclipse is telling me that I have an exception but I can't find it

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;



    public class event extends JFrame {


    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JButton Load;
    private JButton Edit;
    private JButton Delete;
    private int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    public event() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Load = new JButton("Load");
        add(Load);

        Edit = new JButton("Edit");
        add(Edit);

        Delete = new JButton("Delete");
        add(Delete);

        label = new JLabel("");
        add(label);

        label2 = new JLabel("");
        add(label2);

        label3 = new JLabel("");
        add(label3);

        event e = new event();
        Load.addActionListener((ActionListener) e);

        event2 ev = new event2();
        Edit.addActionListener((ActionListener) ev);

        event3 eve = new event3();
        Delete.addActionListener((ActionListener) eve);

    }

    public class events implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (x == 0) {
                label.setText("Load file");
                x=1;
            } else if (x == 1) {
                label.setText("");
                x=0;
            }

        }
    }

    public class event2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            if (y == 0) {
                label2.setText("Edit file");
                y=1;
            } else if (y == 1) {
                label2.setText("");
                y=0;
            }
        }

    }

    public class event3 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve) {
            if (z == 0) {
                label3.setText("Delete file");
                z=1;
            } else if (z == 1) {
                label3.setText("");
                z=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        event gui = new event();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(600, 200);
        gui.setTitle("BASIC GUI");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception is eclipse telling you you have? Where? Print the stacktrace.

Comment: It says it in my main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the constructor of the outer class "event" which extends Frame you accidently create another object of the same class(instead of an "events" object), here's the mentioned line

```
event e = new event();
Load.addActionListener((ActionListener) e);
```

probably causes one main problem:

- it creates an infinite loop of object creation which calls another constructor, which creates another object... and thus at some point a StackOverflowException

I renamed the outer class(the Frame) GUITest, the first ActionEventHandler event1 and so on and so forth

this code worked for me

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUITest extends JFrame {

  private JLabel label;
  private JLabel label2;
  private JLabel label3;
  private JButton Load;
  private JButton Edit;
  private JButton Delete;
  private int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;


  public GUITest() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Load = new JButton("Load");
    add(Load);

    Edit = new JButton("Edit");
    add(Edit);

    Delete = new JButton("Delete");
    add(Delete);

    label = new JLabel("");
    add(label);

    label2 = new JLabel("");
    add(label2);

    label3 = new JLabel("");
    add(label3);

    event1 e1 = new event1();
    Load.addActionListener((ActionListener) e1);

    event2 e2 = new event2();
    Edit.addActionListener((ActionListener) e2);

    event3 e3 = new event3();
    Delete.addActionListener((ActionListener) e3);

  }

  public class event1 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(x == 0) {
        label.setText("Load file");
        x = 1;
      } else if(x == 1) {
        label.setText("");
        x = 0;
      }

    }
  }

  public class event2 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      if(y == 0) {
        label2.setText("Edit file");
        y = 1;
      } else if(y == 1) {
        label2.setText("");
        y = 0;
      }
    }

  }

  public class event3 implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve) {
      if(z == 0) {
        label3.setText("Delete file");
        z = 1;
      } else if(z == 1) {
        label3.setText("");
        z = 0;
      }
    }
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    GUITest gui = new GUITest();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setSize(600, 200);
    gui.setTitle("BASIC GUI");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I can't believe I made such a basic mistake T-T

Comment: @ReinbowAisu no problem, we all began small and learned it the hard way;

also don't forget to mark your question as answered.

happy coding!

Comment: There are no two classes with the same name in the code that the OP provided.

Comment: @lupz oh yes you are right, but accidently because of that naming he created in the constructor of the event class another event object instead of an eventS object - gonna edit it

Answer (score 1):

You end up in an infinite loop because you are creating a `new event()` inside the constructor of the `event`-class.
The constuctor-method calls creates a new event, which creates a new event, which creates a new event and so on... this will result in a `StackOverflowError`.

This is what I get from the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.CGraphicsConfig.nativeGetBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.CGraphicsConfig.getBounds(CGraphicsConfig.java:56)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:19)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:40)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:40)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:40)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:40)
at uitest.event.<init>(event.java:40)
...
```

You see that `event.<init>` (the constructor) is called over and over.
I'd bet you wanted to use the `ActionListener`-class `events` instead of the event class itself.

```
public event() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Load = new JButton("Load");
    add(Load);

    Edit = new JButton("Edit");
    add(Edit);

    Delete = new JButton("Delete");
    add(Delete);

    label = new JLabel("");
    add(label);

    label2 = new JLabel("");
    add(label2);

    label3 = new JLabel("");
    add(label3);

    /*
     * Use events instead of event here.
     */
    events e = new events();
    Load.addActionListener((ActionListener) e);

    event2 ev = new event2();
    Edit.addActionListener((ActionListener) ev);

    event3 eve = new event3();
    Delete.addActionListener((ActionListener) eve);

}
```